# Setting Up Pointer Properly

Tags: java

I am trying to fix my method that I supposed to take a user input node and then display the necessary moves to get from the user input to the goal node. In the method, **answer** represents the goal node. So my methodology was that was that while answer has a parent, you display it and then continue that way but my method is not working how it is supposed to.

For example, if the answer (goal) was 7 and the user inputted 5, I want this method to say 6 then 7 because those are the steps taken from the input to get to the goal. However my method prints out 6 then 5. It will get the first step then backtrack to my input. Im certain it is an issue with the pointers but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
     while(answer.getParent() != null){
        System.out.print(answer.getParent());
        answer = answer.getParent();
```

Comment: can you specify the structure of the graph? which one is which one's parent?

Comment: @KevinHeKev it would look like what I edited. 5 is the parent of 6 and 6 is the parent of 7

Comment: According to your data structure , the grapth have direction 7-->6-->5. So your code will print 6 5 for sure .

Comment: @howie that is the problem. I need the code to print 6 7 but cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stack, either one that you define or the call stack.  To use a call stack, you'd write the code recursively.  To use a user defined [stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), you'd do something like

```
Deque<String> steps = new ArrayDeque<>();
while (answer.getParent() != null) {
    steps.addFirst(answer.toString());
    answer = answer.getParent();
}

while (!steps.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(steps.removeFirst());
}
```

You could also make the stack of the same type as `answer.getParent()` returns and leave out the `toString`.  But I don't know the type, so I didn't try to do that.

A recursive method would look something like

```
public void displayPath(Node answer) {
    if (answer.getParent() == null) {
        return;
    }

    displayPath(answer.getParent());

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

I called the type `Node`.  This may be wrong, as I don't what the right type is.  I'm just guessing.  Replace as necessary.

Note that you have to do the output after the recursive call so that it will print as it returns up the call stack.  If you put it before, it will print in reverse order.

In short, your code generates the list in reverse order.  So you have to display in reverse order.  I think that talking about pointers here is confusing the issue.  You're climbing from child to parent.  So your output is child first then parent.  But if your nodes can have multiple children, you have to climb child to parent.  Or you'd end up doing a search of the full tree and still have to store your path.